# May I know how to auto calculate total price in the text field?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to calculate the total price javascript function. If the user enters the quantity, the total price will be shown automatically in the total price field.

```
     <div class="form-group">

<p class="form-control" name="price" id="price" readonly><span>Price (mmk):</span> <?php echo $row['Price'] ?></p>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input name="qty" id="qty" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Total price (mmk):</label>
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="result" id="result" onClick="total()" disabled> 
</div>


function total() {
  var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('qty').value);

  var price = parseInt(document.getElementById('price').value);

  var total = price * quantity;

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = total;
  document.getElementById('result').value = total;
}
```

Comment: this is the javascript i tried 
function total() {
  var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('qty').value);

  var price = parseInt(document.getElementById('price').value);

  var total = price * quantity;

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = total;
  document.getElementById('result').value = total;
}

Comment: You have other issues with your form structure. For a start, why have you printed the price in a paragraph tag? I could well be a read-only text box. Second, you should use the same name for *name* and *id*. Your output box is `name="txtTotal"` with `id="result"`. Fix these first.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you put in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your input elements, here's what I believe you should do.

```
<div class="form-group">

<p class="form-control" name="price" id="price" readonly><span>Price (mmk):</span> <?php echo $row['Price'] ?></p>

</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input name="qty" id="qty" onkeyup="total()"" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Total price (mmk):</label>
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="result" id="result" disabled> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function total() {
      var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('qty').value);

      var price = <?php echo $row['Price'] ?>;

      var total = price * quantity;

      document.getElementById('result').value = total;
    }

</script>
```

From the above code, please note that

- variable names are case sensitive
- I'm using the `onkeyup` event so that everytime the user types a value and releases the key, the function recalculates the amount.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an onChange or a keyup event.

I have created a basic example for you below

```js
const qtyEl = document.getElementById('quantity');
const valEl = document.getElementById('value');
const totalEl = document.getElementById('autoValue');

const setTotal = () => {
  let qty = qtyEl.value;
  let value = valEl.value;
  totalEl.innerHTML = qty * value;
}
```

```html
<label for="quantity">Qty:</label>
<input type="text"  onkeyup="setTotal()" id="quantity" value=1>

<label for="value">Value:</label>
<input type="text" onkeyup="setTotal()" id="value" value=1>

<p id="autoValue">value will go here</p>
```

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. and after submit the form you can get the value like.

```
$price = $_POST['price'];
   $Quantity = $_POST['qty'];
   $result = $_POST['result'];
```

Code.

```js
 
     function total() {
  var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('qty').value);

  var price = parseInt(document.getElementById('price').value);

  var total = price * quantity;

  document.getElementById('show_result').value = total;
  document.getElementById('result').value = total;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <!-- Create a input hidden field and put the price as value -->
 <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="price" id="price" value="10">


 <!-- display the price value in span -->
 <span>Price (mmk):</span> 10</p>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input name="qty" id="qty" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" onkeyup="total()" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Total price (mmk):</label> 
<!-- Create a input hidden field result and put the total value onkeyup the  Quantity field-->
<input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="result" id="result"> 

<!-- Create read only  text input field  and put the total value onkeyup the Quantity field to display -->
<input class="form-control" type="number" id="show_result"  readonly> 
</div>
```